# Is there a single-word synonym for "preserved" as in "Fruits preserved in syrup."?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

> To preserve - To prepare (food or any perishable substance) so as to resist decomposition or fermentation.

Is there a single-word synonym for "preserved" as in "Fruits preserved in syrup."?

Comment: There is a single word for the entire phrase "fruits preserved in syrup": _compote_.

Comment: Is the syrup preserving the fruit or is it just packaged in syrup?  Do you need to reference the state of the fruit or can you just say "fruit in syrup"?

Comment: What's wrong with the word "preserve"? In BrE, a fruit preserve is basically fruit in sugar syrup.

Comment: @AndrewLeach; I think that Luis is implying something different. Preserve usually refers to jam but I think they mean fruit that has been preserved whole in the syrup like how pickles are preserved in brine. Canned strawberries or peaches for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the preservation technique involves sugar, you can say *[conserve](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/conserved)*

> to preserve (a foodstuff, esp fruit) with sugar [*Collins*]

The term *[put up](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/put-up)* is also used

> to preserve or can (jam, etc) [*Collins*]

The term *[canned](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/canned)* is also used

> preserved in airtight cans or jars [*Collins*]

Interestingly, while canning originally referred to storing foods in metal containers, it continued to be used when glass jars became a standard method, especially for preservation done in the home.

Comment: Canning was originally developed to help Napolean feed his armies, and it was done in glass jars as nothing else was available. Not suprisingly, a lot of them broke so metal containers were developed to replace them. To be 'canned' needs only cooked food in an airtight container of any material.

Comment: @RoaringFish Interesting. What is the French word for *putting up* food?

Comment: I am quite tempted to say *appertisation* (http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/appertisation/) but I am not sure if this a 'real' word, or something coined or resurrected in 2010 when France had the 200th anniversary of Mr Appert inventing canning. From experience, I think the French are more into home freezing than preserving.

Answer (score -1):

another is pickled (but these are all *kinds* of preserving, and not fully synonymous)